# How to give language option at installation time of my .NET project?

Tags: c#, .net, setup-project

I created one desktop project in C#.

I want to know about how it could be used for different languages.
I created an `resx` file for all the forms like that:
select particular form goes to the property window set localiztion true select language in which I want to show in particular language. Convert all labels text and other functionality in selected language and build it.

After building one another `resx` file created other than default `resx`. This process is done for all the form. So now each form having to `resx` file. First is `hi.resx` for hindi and another is default `resx`.

Now my question is that:
How to give language selection option at installation time?

And when user choose any language then my application is converted in that language. That means particular language `resx` file set life time whenever user uninstall that application.

Comment: @Ashwin: there's no such thing as C#.NET. Just "C#".

Answer (score 1):

Easy to do using [NSIS](http://nsis.sf.net).

Not possible using Windows Installer without a bootstrapper.

What are you wanting to use?